# Trying to prove that if two matrices with the same Eigenvectors are summed, the result has the same eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a proof I am tyring to work out:  A and B are square matrices, of same size.  I am trying to show that if the eigenvector V of both and A and B, then v is also an eigenvector of $ M = c_1 A + c_2 B $ and $c_1 , c_2$ are constants.  What is the eigenvalue of $M$?

My logic is as follows:  because it is a square matrix $n$ then the collection of eigenvectors $m = n$  then the matrices are diagonalisable.

$ D = P^{-1} AP$ and $D = P^{-1} BP$ and $D = P^{-1} MP$  therefore the equation shows that   $PDP^{-1} = c_1PDP^{-1} + c_2PDP^{-1}$  and that the eigenvalues of M corresponding to the eigenvector v is the diagonal $D = P^{-1}MP = diag(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n)$

Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

That is way overkill. Matrix multiplication is a linear operation. If we let $M = c_1A + c_2B$ as you did above, what is $Mv$?

Look at this and try to apply the definition of eigenvectors. (A vector $v$ such that $Av = \lambda v$.)

Comment: so if $Mv = \lambda v$  then we could apply $v$ to both sides of the equation, $\lambda v = c_1\lambda v + c_2\lambda v$.  where $Av = \lambda v$ and $Bv = \lambda v$, and $Acv = c\lambda v, c(Av) = c(\lambda v)$  is this on the right trajectory?

Comment: That looks like it's on the right general path. Be careful that $Av = \lambda_1 v$ and $Bv = \lambda_2 v$, but $\lambda_1$ is not necessarily equal to $\lambda_2$ (ie $A$ and $B$ could scale the eigenvector by different amounts).

Comment: so $v$ is the eigenvector of the matrix because applying $\lambda v $ on the left meant that $ v $ was also distributed to the right.  also, the eigenvalues of M corresponding to the eigenvector $v$ is $c_1\lambda_1 + c_2\lambda_2$  The eigenvector of both A and B are the same (as stated by the problem).  Am I missing something?

Comment: meem, please let me know if I am on the right track still?